# What is 'PreCalc' in UpdateListItems?

Tags: sharepoint, caml, spservices

I see some examples with

```
    <Batch OnError="Continue" PreCalc="TRUE" . . .
```

and some that omit that attribute. I have seen zero examples that set it to FALSE.

What does this attribute do?

What would commend a value of TRUE?

What would commend a value of FALSE?

Is the default FALSE? Is it NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my experience it turned out to be useful in successfully creating list items that have lookup columns to BCS External List,
other wise you wouldn't be able to create one.